# How to implement a matrix exponential in a quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, hamiltonian-simulation

Maybe it is a naive question, but I cannot figure out how to actually exponentiate a matrix in a quantum circuit.
Assuming to have a generic square matrix *A*, if I want to obtain its exponential, $e^{A}$, i can use the series

$$e^{A} \simeq I+ A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!}+...$$

To have its approximation. I do not get how to do the same using quantum gates then apply it for instance to perform an Hamiltonian simulation. Some help?

Comment: It's not clear whether you are talking of a quantum circuit that takes $A$ as input and outputs $e^A$ or Hamiltonian simulation (i.e. build a circuit whose unitary matrix match $e^{iA}$).

Comment: My bad; what I meant is, taken a matrix A, I want to have in my circuit its exponential, $e^{iA}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reformulating your question:

> How to perform Hamiltonian Simulation for a generic square matrix $A$?

**Quick answer**: it is not possible.

The goal of Hamiltonian Simulation (HS) is to find a quantum circuit (i.e. a succession of gates) that acts like $U(t) = e^{-iAt}$ on a quantum state. Here $U(t)$ needs to be unitary (because of the properties of quantum gates) and so $e^{-iAt}$ needs also to be unitary.

So the HS algorithm is only applicable to matrices $A$ such that $e^{-iAt}$ is unitary. Every hermitian matrix satisfy this property, but not every `generic square matrix` does. Depending on your problem, this limitation may or may not be an issue but you can't use HS if $e^{-iAt}$ is not unitary.

For example for the [HHL algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171) (that use HS of $A$ as a subroutine) with a system $Ax=b$, if $e^{-iAt}$ is not unitary you can instead consider the problem
$$Cy = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ A^\dagger & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ x\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}b \\ 0\end{pmatrix},$$ 
solve it with HHL (which is now possible because the new matrix $C$ is hermitian) and recover $x$.

So the interesting question is now:

> How to perform Hamiltonian Simulation for a given hermitian matrix $A$?

And the answer will depend on the properties of $A$.

This is a huge research topic and there are plenty of things to say on it. I will not present every methods here as they are quite complicated and I did not understand all of them. Here is a list of papers/presentations that are related to HS and that may be interesting to start with HS:

1. [Simulating Hamiltonian dynamics on a small quantum computer](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~amchilds/talks/ibm13.pdf): slides about HS. Even if it is a presentation, this is the most complete source I found on Hamiltonian Simulation. It presents quickly 3 different methods and cites interesting papers for each method.
2. [Lecture Notes on Quantum Algorithms (Andrew M. Childs, 2017)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~amchilds/qa/qa.pdf): recent and rather complete. HS is discussed in chapter 25 (page 123).
3. [Exponential improvement in precision for simulating sparse Hamiltonians](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1414v2): presents in details one of the 3 methods presented in 1.
4. [Efficient quantum algorithms for simulating sparse Hamiltonians](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0508139.pdf): presents in details another of the 3 methods presented in 1.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the references, I will take a look at them!

Comment: I recommend you to start with the first reference. It's the most complete and it gives link to other articles. 
For me (personal point of view), the first technique using Trotter-Suzuki formula is the most understandable. But it may not be the same for you!

Comment: *Every hermitian matrix satisfy this property*: more specifically, *all and only* Hermitian matrices have this property